Ceiling light emits a dim glow even when turned off
My ceiling light emits a dim glow even when turned off. Here's a picture of the inside. I’m not sure how to fix it—any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! 

Some times if a LED light is on a dimmer, this happens.  LEDs must be made for dimmers and dimmer must be for LEDs.

What is the switch for this light?

Is that ground connected correctly? (Unrelated, but potentially hazardous if not.)

This is typical of an LED on one of:

a lighted (typically neon) switch or (electronic) timer switch where the current from the neon light or electronic timer passes through the light bulb for power (which would not light up an incandescent bulb filament as it's a small current.)
A non-LED dimmer.
An LED dimmer that needs to have the "off" point adjusted.


Some 3-way switch setups can also cause this, similar to CFL bulbs flashing weakly every few seconds.
